# Questions using R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am interested in extending a shiny application that I am building and need some guidance or assistance for what I would like to accomplish.

Currently, I have a shiny application that takes a `textInput` and searches a database given an Id in the `textInput`. The `mainPanel` displays all of the relevant information for that Id with different `tabs`.

I would like to now extend the application to search multiple Ids. Ideally, the search against multiple Ids would return a data table showing the Id and the name for each Id. From there I would like to be able to click on the Id and it take me to the `mainPanel` that I have already built. I have looked around in the shiny tutorials and gallery but can not find what I am looking for.

I am looking for suggestions and documentation on how I can extend the shiny application with this criteria. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the `server.R` and `ui.R` code.

```
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)
library(DT)
library(RgoogleMaps)
library(Matrix)
library(dplyrimpaladb)
library(dplyr)
library(lazy)
library(testthat)
library(RJDBC)
library(DBI)
library(rJava)
library(assertthat)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  options(dplyr.jdbc.classpath = "/Impala/impala-jdbc-cdh5")
  usr_ryan <- reactive({ src_impaladb(dbname='usr_ryan', host='localhost') })

  queryString <- reactive({ gsub("id_number",
                                 input$id,
                                 "SELECT * FROM table where id='id_number'") })

  data <- reactive({ head(tbl(usr_ryan(), sql(queryString()))) })

  output$summary <- Summary(data)

  output$address <- Address(data)

  output$googlemap <- plotGoogleMap(data)

})
```

`ui.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(Matrix)
library(jsonlite)
library(DT)
library(RgoogleMaps)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Id Summary"),

  sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel(
  textInput("npi", label = h3("Enter Id:"), value = "1")

  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Information", DT::dataTableOutput("summary"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("address"), plotOutput("googlemap"))
      )
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: You described several functions you want to implement. Which one of them are you having problem, and what is the specific problem?

Comment: I am looking for documentation on where I can find out how to implement this.